# Remove duplicates with row pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, for-loop, pivot

I want to get rid of duplicates in one column (device_name) but keep related data from another column (app_id). Each device can have couple of applications (1 -> x, usually between 1-5) so  I want to put those app identifiers into a new columns which I want to  call [APP1],[APP2],[APP3] and so on. The best option would be kind of dynamic Pivot, but any static solution will be welcome as well. 
Thanks for  help in advance.

PS
I came up with below code what so ever, but in only concatenate APP id's separated by comas into one column.

```
    USE tempdb;
    SELECT  DEVICE_NAME,
        NoOfApps,
        STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + APP_ID
                FROM    dbo.Aperture_full_test apps
                WHERE   apps.DEVICE_NAME = Aperture_full_test.DEVICE_NAME
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS Appid

    FROM    (   SELECT  DEVICE_NAME, COUNT(DEVICE_NAME) AS NoOfApps
            FROM    dbo.Aperture_full_test
            GROUP BY DEVICE_NAME     
        ) Aperture_full_test
        ORDER BY NoOfApps DESC
```

Data sample:

```
    USE tempdb;
    GO

    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Aperture_full_test') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.Aperture_full_test;
    GO

    CREATE TABLE dbo.Aperture_full_test
    (
    DEVICE_NAME   varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    APP_ID        varchar(10) NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO dbo.Aperture_full_test(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID)
    VALUES('LDNSQLF700', 157848);
    INSERT INTO dbo.Aperture_full_test(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID)
    VALUES('LDNSQLF700', 155439);
    INSERT INTO dbo.Aperture_full_test(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID)
    VALUES('LDNSQLF700', 635533);
    INSERT INTO dbo.Aperture_full_test(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID)
    VALUES('NYSQL502', 189164);
    INSERT INTO dbo.Aperture_full_test(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID)
    VALUES('NYSQL502', 188641);
    INSERT INTO dbo.Aperture_full_test(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID)
    VALUES('AUSSQL140', 537990);
    INSERT INTO dbo.Aperture_full_test(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID)
    VALUES('AUSSQL140', 1349605);
    INSERT INTO dbo.Aperture_full_test(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID)
    VALUES('JAP543X2', 5646789);
    INSERT INTO dbo.Aperture_full_test(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID)
    VALUES('EU456CLX', 6545789);
    INSERT INTO dbo.Aperture_full_test(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID)
    VALUES('EUCTX654', 5637965);
    INSERT INTO dbo.Aperture_full_test(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID)
    VALUES('EUCTX654', 6464367) ;
    INSERT INTO dbo.Aperture_full_test(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID)
    VALUES('EUCTX654', 1323123) ;
    INSERT INTO dbo.Aperture_full_test(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID)
    VALUES('EUCTX654', 1004326) ;
    GO
```

Comment: **STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + APP_ID**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server you can implement the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function.

If you have a known number of values then you can hard code the query using the following:

```
select device_name, App1, App2, App3, App4, App5
from
(
  select device_name, app_id,
    'App'+
      cast(row_number() over(partition by device_name 
                            order by device_name) as varchar(10)) col
  from Aperture_full_test
) d
pivot
(
  max(app_id)
  for col in (App1, App2, App3, App4, App5)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9bdd3/10).

But if you are going to have an unknown number of app_ids for each device, then you can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME('App'+cast(rn as varchar(10))) 
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by device_name 
                                              order by device_name) rn
                      from Aperture_full_test
                    ) d
                    group by rn
                    order by rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT device_name, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select device_name, app_id,
                  ''App''+
                    cast(row_number() over(partition by device_name 
                                          order by device_name) as varchar(10)) col
                from Aperture_full_test
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(app_id)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9bdd3/11). Both give the result:

```
| DEVICE_NAME |    APP1 |    APP2 |    APP3 |    APP4 |
-------------------------------------------------------
|   AUSSQL140 |  537990 | 1349605 |  (null) |  (null) |
|    EU456CLX | 6545789 |  (null) |  (null) |  (null) |
|    EUCTX654 | 5637965 | 6464367 | 1323123 | 1004326 |
|    JAP543X2 | 5646789 |  (null) |  (null) |  (null) |
|  LDNSQLF700 |  157848 |  155439 |  635533 |  (null) |
|    NYSQL502 |  189164 |  188641 |  (null) |  (null) |
```

Edit, If you want to count the total number of devices for each server, then you can use  `count() over()`. The hard-coded version will be:

```
select device_name, TotalDevices, App1, App2, App3, App4, App5
from
(
  select device_name, app_id,
    'App'+
      cast(row_number() over(partition by device_name 
                            order by device_name) as varchar(10)) col,
    count(app_id) over(partition by device_name) TotalDevices  -- add this line
  from Aperture_full_test
) d
pivot
(
  max(app_id)
  for col in (App1, App2, App3, App4, App5)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9bdd3/13)

Comment: One more question - is there a chance to add another column to the dynamic SQL code (presented above), which will provide count of applications for each server? I have tried 100 times to modify the code but looks like I failed and have to give up.

Comment: @Mario Yes, you can use `count(app_id) over(partition by device_name)` to get the total number of devices for each server.  See my edit, I added a static version of the query with the new column.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pivot query, which can be done in the group by.  What you need is a sequence number for the Apps.

```
select aft.deviceName, COUNT(*) as NumApps,
       MAX(case when seqnum = 1 then App_id end) as App1,
       MAX(case when seqnum = 2 then App_id end) as App2,
       MAX(case when seqnum = 3 then App_id end) as App3,
       MAX(case when seqnum = 4 then App_id end) as App4,
       MAX(case when seqnum = 5 then App_id end) as App5
from (select aft.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by device_name order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from Aperture_full_test aft
     ) aft
group by aft.deviceName
order by NumApps desc
```

This version does not have the Apps in a particular order becasue the xml code did not have them in a particular order.

Comment: Thanks for this code. It really works and it's nice and clear. Looks like I finally understand "over partytion by" procedure.